# IONIC 3: How do I get geolocation co-ordinates when device aeroplane mode is enabled?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a mobile application created in IONIC 3. I have used

1. Ionic native geolocation plugin - get coordinates
2. Diagnostic plugin - check if the location is already enable
3. Location accuracy plugin - manually enable location

I have also used the SQLite plugin to store the data so that the user can use the application when he is offline too. Everything is fine up to this. I can get the geolocation coordinates when the internet is ON and the internet is OFF too. But the issue raised when the user enables his aeroplane mode.

The **Expected behaviour is** - when the user goes on a particular page it should check if a location is enabled, if not it will ask him to do that.

But now (on the aeroplane mode) it logs the error to the console.

> code - 3
>   Message - Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog not created.

I have tried the same on 2 3 devices. As I read somewhere that some devices work/give(geolocation co-ords) on aeroplane mode and some are not.